# Handle Empty #text in XML DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom

I have an XML document of the following format:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <type>link</type>
        <name>Nyan Cat!</name>
        <author></author>
        <content>http://nyan.cat/</content>
    </item>

    <item>
        <type>quote</type>
        <name>Belief and Intelligence</name>
        <author>Robert Anton Wilson</author>
        <content>Belief is the death of intelligence.</content>
    </item>
</root>
```

As you can see, all `item` tags have the children `type, name, author, content`, however for some cases, the `author` tag might contain an empty `#text` child.

In a Javascript file, I have the following code to get the text values of these tags from the `item` DOM element:

```
this.type = item.getElementsByTagName("type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
this.name = item.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
this.author = item.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
this.content = item.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

The variable `item` is the DOM element for the `<item>` tag. The code runs fine when the author is non-empty, but when `author` is empty, the code does not run. How do I solve this? If `author` is empty, then I want its node value to be the empty string `""`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check for "undefined" on each property of the tree. As in:

`if( typeof (element) == "undefined" ){
//set var to empty string
}`

If you try to access a property of a javascript that is null or undefined, the script will fail at that line and not execute any lines after it.

To get around failing, you can wrap those blocks of code that may fail in a `try{}catch(e){}`

Comment: It's also worth it to check for null in the same block:

if( typeof (element) == "undefined" || element != null ){ //do something with this value } 

Not checking for null can also trip up your code.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should check how many childNodes does the author have:

```
if (item.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes.length == 0) {
    this.author = '';
} else {
    this.author = item.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```